# Can we share image/text to whatsapp to specific contact number in android

Tags: android, image, sharing, whatsapp

In my application i need to share image/text to whatsapp. Sharing images or text is working fine. But my requirement is sharing images/text to specific recipant. For that i have mobile number. So before sharing, first of all that number is having whatsapp or not?. Then if the number having whatsapp, then bydefault select that specific number. If the number is not having whatsapp then simply redirect to whatspp. then they select the recipant and share to that recipant.

For sharing i am using the following code. This code is working fine for sharing.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
if (images.size() > 0) {
    Log.e("count==", "val@@ " + images.size());
    shareIntent
            .putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, images);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

} else {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
}
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

try {
    startActivity(shareIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(ManageOnlineBuyLeadActivity.this,
            "Whatsapp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

And for sharing particular recipant i have changed the follwing lines

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

to

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("smsto:+number");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mUri);
```

But it is not working. For this i googled alot. So please guide me how to do this. Is it possible to share particular recipant or not?

Thank you all..

Comment: have you got the solution of your problem .. if u have please share b'cause i m have this same problem

Comment: we can not send to particular recipient we can redirect to chat screen only. then he can select the recipient there

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is by calling the following method (Use the String variable `message` to input the text you want to send via WhatAapp):

```
private void sendWhatsapp(String message){ 
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(); 
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); 
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) { 
        startActivity(sendIntent); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to send text only to a specific recipient. For sending an image to a specific recipient I am also using this.

```
String smsNumber = "Your specific contact No. here! ";
String msg = "Your message here!";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+smsNumber +"&text="+msg);

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```